# How to show only one category in breadcrumb navigation

Tags: categories, functions, menus, breadcrumb

I added breadcrumb navigation to WordPress & I'm facing one problem. Here's the function.php code of the breadcrumb:

```
function ux_breadcrumbs() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        bloginfo('name');
        echo "</a> » ";
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            the_category('/');
            echo " » ";
            if (is_single()) {
                echo "  ";
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is displaying all categories of the post. I just want it to display only one category. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the help...here's one more thing:

I want to know how to display category > sub category in the breadcrumb if exists.

Comment: For posts that have multiple (or hierarchical) categories, how will you determine which category is the correct one to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_category()` function used to retrieve categories array of a post, and `array_shift()` function used to get the first item of an array.

You possibly need this -

```
function ux_breadcrumbs() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        bloginfo('name');
        echo "</a> » ";
        if (is_category() || is_single() )
        {
            if( is_category() )
            {
                single_term_title();
            }
            elseif (is_single() )
            {
                echo " » ";
                $cats = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                $cat = array_shift($cats);
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name ) ) . '">'. $cat->name .'</a>';
                echo "  ";
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..!!! One more thing! Do you know how to show "Category > Sub Category" if exist in this above code?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, change the question or post a new one and i will answer. thanks.

Comment: I updated the question. Please help me now. Thanks!